# OpenCV Neural Network train one iteration at a time

Tags: c++, opencv

The only way I know to train a multilayer neural network in OpenCV is:

```
CvANN_MLP network;
....
network.train(input, output, Mat(), Mat(), params, flags);
```

But this will not print out any meaningful debug (e.g. Iteration count, current error,...), the program will just sit there until it finishes training, very troublesome if the dataset is in gigabytes, there's no way I can see the progress.

How do I train the network one iteration at a time, or print out some debug while training?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't find it possible... I'm trying to figure out what it's doing with LBPH Face Recognizer for a week, but the functions just won't reveal themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem not solved, but question solved. Answer: It's impossible as far as the current OpenCV versions are concerned.

Answer (score 1):

Are you setting the UPDATE_WEIGHTS flags?

You can test the error yourself by having the ANN predict the result vector for each sample in the training set.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/ml_neural_networks.html#cvann-mlp-train
the params parameter is of Type cvANN_MLP_TrainParams. This class contains a property TermCriteria which controls the when the training function terminates. This Termination criteria class http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html can be set to terminate after a given number of iterations or when a given epsilon conditions is fulfilled or some combination of both. I have not used the training function myself so I can't know the code that you'd use to make this work, but something like this should limit the number of training cycles

```
CvANN_MLP_TrainParams params = CvANN_MLP_TrainParams()

params.term_crit.type = 1;//This should tell the train function you want to terminate on number of iterations
params.term_crit.maxCount = 1;//Termination after one iteration might be max_iter instead of maxCount

network.train(input, output, Mat(),Mat(), params, flags)
```

Like I said I haven't worked with openCV but having read the documentation something like this should work.

Comment: I did try this approach, however it is not possible to resume training (even with weights saved and loaded) and I couldn't find a way to get the current error.

Comment: Could you add the details of what you tried along these lines and how it failed?

Comment: I would if this comment form allowed embedding code. Anyway it doesn't fail, just not possible to get the current error, the most important piece of information.

Comment: You can edit your question with additional code. Maybe I misunderstand. Shouldn't you be able to compute the error from the known output and the result of calling predict with the input vectors?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer lays in the source code. IF you want to get some output after every x epochs, put something in the source code, in this loop:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/9787ab598b6609a6ca6652a12441d741cb15f695/modules/ml/src/ann_mlp.cpp#L941

When they made OpenCV they had to find a balance between user customizability and how easy it is to use/read. Ultimately you have the power to do whatever you want when editing the source code.